# Makefile: Conditionals in foreach

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to add multiple commands in a foreach loop? I'm trying to add a simple if-else conditional but unfortunately I cannot find a good explanation for that.

Foreach lib in TARGET_LIBS, I would like to check if lib contains the word "test". If yes, call TEST_COPY_RULE. Otherwise, call LIB_COPY_RULE.

Thank you

Comment: `ifneq` is a directive, not a function, so no. You might be able to use the `if` function. Either way this looks like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem, you should describe what you are trying to solve, not your solution alone.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question so it wont be a XY problem. Let me know if it still is

Comment: You've paraphrased your original question, it hadn't really changed. Why do you need two separate rules in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Makefile answers your question positively:

```
TARGET_LIBS := a testb ctest d e
TEST_COPY_RULE = $(info TEST_COPY $1)
LIB_COPY_RULE = $(info LIB_COPY $1)
IS_TEST = $(findstring test, $L)

$(foreach L, $(TARGET_LIBS), $(if $(call IS_TEST,$L),$(call TEST_COPY_RULE, $L),$(call LIB_COPY_RULE, $L)) )
```